# build tensorflow lite on other platform (such as Linux)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

As tensorflow lite is for the mobile device, I just wondered if it can be built on Linux platform? how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you need to build on Linux and run on mobile, which would be the default use case, but I am guessing you want to build and run on Linux. In this case, check out the [example code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/label_image/label_image.cc),
and build and run on your linux machine like this:

```
# From the Tensorflow repo root
bazel build '//tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/label_image'
bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/label_image \
    -m my_model.tflite
    -i my_image.bmp
    -m labels.txt
```

You can find the labels file [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/android/app/src/main/assets/labels_mobilenet_quant_v1_224.txt):

If you want to build your own code check out the [BUILD file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/label_image/BUILD) and edit to your needs.

I don't know exactly what the dependencies are, but if you use the tensorflow development docker image `tensorflow/tensorflow:1.10.0-devel` you don't need to worry about that

Comment: Thanks, I need to both build and run on linux using lite model.

Comment: The tensorflow team is moving everything out of contrib on the master branch for their 2.0 launch, I've edited it to point to the 1.12 release